# Android: Support Fragments don't apply activity theme?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-styles

At the moment, I'm stuck with a very annoying kind of "bug" I assume regarding all Pre-Lollipop Android versions. It appears that (support) fragments don't apply the activity's theme they're assigned to. To make my explanations a bit easier, have the following demonstration:

My app runs with a turquoise theme at first. Let's say, the user decided to change the turquoise theme to a red theme. He or she restarts the app and is greeted with the following:

[image: Android 4.4.2 tablet: the theme doesn't apply to the fragment]

*(screenshot taken on an Android 4.4.2 tablet)*

Terrible sight, isn't it? However, if I run the same app in an emulator with Android L the whole theme problem doesn't even seem to exist.

[image: Android 5.0.1: the theme applies to the fragment]

There's especially one thing which seems odd about the tablet screenshot. The fragment itself doesn't apply the theme but child components inside the fragment which get added lateron (like the view with the exclamation mark which is hosted by a ViewPager) take and apply the theme as if nothing happened.

I'm not quite sure what the issue might be. I've done everything as stated in every document available. I set the theme before I call `setContentView(resource)` in the corresponding activity. I tried to do the trick with `ContextThemeWrapper` but it was no use.

Relevant code:

- [The activity's `onCreate()`](http://pastebin.com/sLPBfwMy)
- [The fragment's `onCreateView()`](http://pastebin.com/r0WC8HAY)
- [The fragment's layout](http://pastebin.com/y8s1r8NZ)
- [Attributes](http://pastebin.com/rDMfKMkH)
- [Themes (a lot of them)](http://pastebin.com/RLHhVCEf)

I tried to resolve this issue for days now and I still can't find out why this is not working. I haven't found a suitable answer yet and would love some advise.

Answer (score 0):

I've been the victim to my own stupidity. I had another close look on my project setup and found this:

[image]

My tablet takes its layout resources from the sw600dp-folder, but I forgot to change the corresponding layout to take attributes instead of hardcoded colors. I think I have to retire after making such a stupid mistake.